# return statement in lambda expression

Tags: c++, boost-lambda

I created a lambda expression inside my `std::for_each` call.

In it there is code like this one, but I have building error telling me that

```
error: expected primary-expression before ‘return’
error: expected `]' before ‘return’
```

In my head I think that `boost-lambda` works mainly with functors, so since `return` statement it isn't like that, calling it doesn't work.

Do you know what it is and how to fix it?

Thanks
AFG

```
namespace bl = boost::lambda;
int a, b;
bl::var_type::type a_( bl::var( a ) );
bl::var_type::type b_( bl::var( b ) );

std::for_each( v.begin(), v.end(), (
// ..do stuff here
if_(  a_ > _b_ )
[
std::cout << _1,
 return
]
));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use `return` instruction inside lambda expression. Use constructions like `if_then_else_return`. They offer syntax that allows producing results. 
But in your case `return` is not even required, just throw it away.

Answer (score 4):

just forget boost-lambda and use the new standard C++ lambda expression instead.

[Explanation & Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293608.aspx)

Comment: Actually he better does not use lambdas here, check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

@MBZ is right, use C++11 (but **not lambda** in this case).

Here is your code with C++11:

```
int a, b;
std::vector<int> v;
for(int e : v)
{
  if(a > b)
    std::cout << e;
}
```

Of course you *could* do the same with lambdas, but *why complicating it* like the code below?

```
int a, b;
std::vector<int> v;
std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), 
  [&a,&b](int e)
  {
    if(a > b)
      std::cout << e;
  }
);
```